# How to find Kentico hotfix when KIM is not installed

Tags: kentico, hotfix

On my development machine I can view the hotfix level of the Kentico website using KIM. KIM isn't installed on our production machines.

In Kentico v7.0 the hotfix level was reported in CMS Desk but that isn't the case in Kentico v9.0.

Is there anywhere I can look to find the hotfix level without using KIM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are typically a few places you can find this:

1. Database
2. File system
3. Kentico UI

If you get your info from the database, it will only be relevant to the data.  If you get your info from the file system, it will tell you the version of the files.  If you look in the Kentico UI, it will show you what is in the database.

To get the info out of the database run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CMS_SettingsKey
WHERE KeyName = 'CMSDataVersion' OR
KeyName = 'CMSDBVersion' OR
KeyName = 'CMSHotfixVersion'
```

The `KeyValue` fields will have the info you are looking for.

To get the info from the file system, go to the Bin directory and right click on any of the CMS dll's and go to properties>details.  The Product Version will provide you with the version information.

In the file system you can also find the hotfix in a txt file under /App_Data/Install/Hotfix.txt

To get the info from the UI, log into Kentico and click the question mark at the top right of the screen, it will show the current version.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me confirm the upgrade. For UI,  is clicking question mark the only way? One would expect version to be displayed in the System application.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Also, the UI version can be different that what you see in the dlls and database so be sure to check all locations to ensure EVERYTHING was upgraded properly.

Answer (score 4):

In the user interface (admin) in Help toolbar.
[image]

You can also find it in database in *CMS_SettingsKey* table. Look for *CMSHotfixVersion* KeyName.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the admin panel and click on the "?" icon on your right side of the screen. This will open a sliding area revealing you the correct hotfix version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply hotfix and we don't have KIM in system then you can download the utility directly and apply it.

Hotfix URL
http://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes