# How to find out Kentico Version without having access to Admin or Database

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I have source code of a Kentico site to review but do not have access to database or live Portal yet. I was wondering if there is a way to find out the CMS version just from the files or Code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the version of any main DLL. The name starts with the prefix cms.
For example take CMS.DataEngine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter :) It is the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to determine the version as described in this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650566

1. File system - look at details of dll in bin directory and hotfix.txt file
2. Kentico UI
3. Database.

All 3 versions and hot fix numbers need to match.